# Have concerns about upgrading 18.04.6 to 20.04 and effects on VMware

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, vmware, vmware-player

I am a Linux newbie (using 18.04 since 2019) and have installed VMware Player 15.5.7 with CRITICAL software (Windows 7) that I don't want to lose.  In a few weeks 18.04 won't be supported.  Hardware = Precision Dell laptop (pre-installed w/Ubuntu).

I'm concerned about upgrading to 20.04 for fear it will break my VMware installation (or I'll have to upgrade VMware and then it maybe won't read my VMs?)  I know enough to be dangerous but don't want to do something stupid.  I could use this machine offline for-e-ver, but if upgrading shouldn't hurt... I'd prefer to do that.

So what actually happens to all the "dot" folders and settings for apps I've installed during an upgrade?  Does everything stay in place or do I need to re-install apps, including VMware?

Very concerned... but need some help/advice before I make a decision on which road to take.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I'm hoping an upgrade leaves app files alone (including VMware) and that 15.5.7 will still run on Ubuntu 20.04.x   Wishful thinking!?

Comment: Your concern is wise, but trusting random internet voices is not. Maybe what works for us won't work for you. There is little certainty in the universe, except for what we make for ourselves. The best advice we can give is to  *manage* your risks the best ways you know how: Backups. VM snapshots. Notes. Returning your system to stock condition. Install media on hand. Plenty of time. Be prepared for problems.

Comment: I hear you. Thanks for your reply.  Excellent point!

Comment: For critical systems I start by buying another machine, usually off-lease. Put the latest LTS Ubuntu on that. Ah, actually, there is a problem with the latest Ubuntu (22.04.02 LTS) and Vmware player 17.02.  Better to use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for now.  Then install the latest VMware player or workstation if that is what your using.  Then COPY your VM over to the new computer and try it.